# Can't insert resource file of glade to project in VS C# express

Tags: c#, glade

I am following this guide: http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpBeginnersGuide it tells me to create a glade file (main.glade in my case), however when I insert it in my project in visual studio I always get this exception:

Cannot get resource file 'main.glade'
Parameter name: resource_name

I tried to flag the file as embedded resource, but it didn't help. How I configure file to be compiled as embedded resource so that it can be accessed by glade? The guide doesn't mention this part

Comment: That link says nothing about visual studio.  It uses the command line compiler: `mcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 helloword.cs`

Comment: That's why I ask here, the tutorial is for cross platform library

Comment: And the answer is, "use the command line compiler like in the tutorial"

Comment: that's not very helpful.

Comment: You can't use Visual Studio express with Gtk because it requires an add-in which the express versions of VS don't support.  Use the command line compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible because the express versions of Visual Studio don't support add-ins and Gtk requires VS add-ins to work in VS.  You can try using Monodevelop or the command line compiler.

From the link:

> Windows: If you are using Windows, pick yourself up a copy of the
>   integrated installer from that Downloads page. You might also like to
>   grab a copy of the Gtk# integration package for Visual Studio which
>   will allow you to use GTK# with Microsoft's Visual Studio without
>   installing the rest of Mono.